# Comma or semi-colon ?When to use

Tags: commas, semicolons

I don't know whether a semicolon or a comma should be used.
For example:

Now that GoT is done for the season what will James complain about besides Disney movies?Find out on a new episode of Off Time Radio;  if he ever texts me back.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably go for *nothing* after ***Radio***, but you could use a dash or a full stop instead of a comma (though I don't think a semicolon would be syntactically valid). There is of course the ambiguity over whether what you will find out from the new episode is what James will complain about next, or whether or not he will ever text the speaker back.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a comma in this case.

A semicolon should only be used when the clauses you're separating can stand on their own as complete sentences. In this case, "Find out on a new episode of Off Time Radio" is a complete sentence, but "if he ever texts me back" is a dependent clause and cannot stand by itself. Thus, it would be incorrect to use a semicolon here.

It would also be incorrect to use an em dash or period for the same reason. These serve the same grammatical function as a semicolon but imply different types of relationships between the joined sentences.